# Технология кроссплатформенной разработки приложения: что лучше?

Tags: reactjs, xamarin, crm

Необходимо создать приложение для службы такси. У них есть собственная CRM система с базой водителей и клиентов. Какую технологию лучше выбрать? xamarin или react native? В первую очередь необходимо создать приложение для iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Если до этого верстали сайт в HTML+CSS и/или вам знаком язык JavaScript - используйте React Native. Если нет - принципиального значение не имеет, дело вкуса..